# Finding the probability (using phi and z scores)

Tags: statistics

X ~ N(15,4)

Find P( X > 18.7 | X > 11.7 ).

Attempt: Rewrite as 
 P ( x > 18.7) - P( x > 11.7)

Using the phi function
\begin{equation*}
\phi(1.85) - \phi(-1.65) = (0.9678) - (0.0495) = 0.9183
\end{equation*}

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Do you have the correct answer? I am writing an answer, but I would like to be sure that it gives you the correct result.

Comment: @Student I think  we both can be almost sure since we both have the same result.

Comment: @callculus: I was just surprised by the small number and since the OP seems to know the correct answer, but not the way to get there, I thought he/she could give us the correct answer. Anyway, I see that I indeed have the same procedure as you have, so you are probably right :)

Comment: @Student I have also calculated the final result and compared it with yours. They were more or less equal.  Thus not only the procedures are equal.

Comment: @callculus: thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a difference between $P(A \cap B)$, being the chance that $A$ and $B$ happen both, and $P(A \mid B)$, being the chance of $A$ happening, given that $B$ happened. So you made a mistake in your definition of conditional probability.

Therefore, applying the correct definition, you will find that
$$p = P(X > 18.7 \mid X > 11.7) = \frac{P(X > 18.7 \cap X > 11.7)}{P(X > 11.7)}$$
Hence we find that 
$$p  = \frac{P(X > 18.7)}{P(X > 11.7)}.$$

We have that $P(X > 18.7) = P(Z > \frac{18.7 - 15}{2}) = P(Z > 1.85)$ and $P(X > 11.7) = P(Z > -1.65)$. Note that 
$$P(Z > 1.85) = 1 - P(Z \leq 1.85) = 1 - \phi(1.85) = 1 - 0.9678 = 0.0322$$
and
$$P(Z > -1.65) = P(Z \leq 1.65) = \phi(1.65) = 0.951$$
where we could take the first equality because of symmetry of the normal distribution with respect to the $y$-axis.

Hence we find that 
$$p = \frac{0.0322}{0.951} = 0.03386.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You should apply the Bayes theorem:

$$P( X > 18.7 | X > 11.7 )=\frac{P(X>18.7\cap X> 11.7)}{P(X>11.7)}=\frac{P(X>18.7)}{P(X>11.7)}=\frac{1-P(X\leq 18.7)}{1-P(X\leq 11.7)}$$